# How to get more accurate orthonormal eigenvectors?

Tags: matrix, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I have a matrix `M` with real entries in `MachinePrecision`. I compute its eigenvectors and construct matrix `U`:

```
  ev = Eigenvectors[M];    
  U = Transpose @ ev;
```

`U` is supposed to be an orthogonal matrix and thus `Transpose[U].U == IdentityMatrix[ Length @ U]`.
*Mathematica* gives the latter equality with the accuracy of `10^(-16)`:

```
Transpose[U].U - IdentityMatrix[ Length @ U]// Abs// Max == 8.8131 * 10^(-16).
```

Is it possible to make this difference smaller, let's say, order of `10^(-32)`? I need to get eigenvectors which are orthonormal with accuracy of order of `10(-32)` or higher.

Comment: you are asking for output that is higher precision than the input

Comment: Basically you cannot have more precision in your eigenvectors than you have in your matrix `M`.  So either you increase the precision of your matrix values "at source" or you *artificially* increase the precision, for example using  [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetPrecision.html).  ***But using `SetPrecision` to increase precision is arbitrarily padding your values with (base 2) zeros, in reality the calculated eigenvectors will be no more precise***. Browse the Related posts for more information.

Comment: Also note that a higher precision at the source may mean significant higher calculation time, since the processor floating point capabilities cannot be used any more.

Comment: Thanks for your comments/answers. In order to increase precision SetPrecision adds noise to the original data so I don't think I want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

a machine precision symmetric matrix:

```
 n = 5;
 m = Nest[ 
     Join[#, {Table[#[[i, (Length[#] + 1)]], {i, Length[#]}]~Join~
            RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {n - Length[#]}]}] & , {} , n];
```

convert the matrix to an exact rational form, do the eignevector extraction and convert back to high precision floats:

```
 ev = N[Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[(Rationalize[#, 10^-16] & /@ m)], 32];
```

your test:

```
 U = Transpose@ev;
 (Transpose[U].U - IdentityMatrix[Length@U] ) // Abs // Max
```

> 0.*10^-32

This is going to quickly get real slow for larger n..

### edit

after working through it the hard way, I'll note the @MikeLimaOscars approach works better (faster), ie.

```
 ev = Eigenvectors[SetPrecision[m, 32]];
```